# Boost Serialization: Serialize/Export derived class without default constructor

Tags: c++11, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I need to serialize all the options on my CommunicationLayer, which is basically a wrapper around serial port, which I will use in an initialization file of sorts.

This class doesn't have a default constructor, but implements a pure virtual class. When I first ran this I got the exception that I didn't register/export the derived class. So I did that. But when I added the export I got the exception that it couldn't find a save/load function:

```
no matching function for call to ‘save(boost_1_69_0::archive::xml_oarchive&, const amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer&, const boost_1_69_0::serialization::version_type&)’
         save(ar, t, v);
```

This is true! But I can't use the save/load and use save_construct_data and load_construct_data, because the absence of a default constructor. How do I tell boost/serde to use these instead?? Is it the SPLIT_FREE macro?

I'm trying to work myself through the documentation, but it's really hard to find everything.

Following are the base and derived classes, I tried to shorten the derived class as much as possible.

```cpp
//BASE
class ICommunicationLayer {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    inline void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {};
public:
    virtual ~ICommunicationLayer();
    virtual std::size_t write(const char* const buffer, std::size_t buffSize) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t readUntil(std::vector<char>& buffer, char delim, std::chrono::microseconds timeout) = 0;
};
```

```cpp
// DERIVED
#include "ICommunicationLayer.h"

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
namespace amp {
namespace communication {

class RS485CommunicationLayer final : public ICommunicationLayer {
public:
    RS485CommunicationLayer(
            const std::string& path,
            unsigned int baud_rate,
            // other options
    );

    ~RS485CommunicationLayer();

    std::size_t write(const char* const buffer, const size_t size) override;
    std::size_t readUntil(std::vector<char>& buffer, char delim,std::chrono::microseconds timeout) override;
    std::string getPath() const;
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    std::string path;
  // rest of impl
};

} /* namespace communication */
} /* namespace amp */

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer)

namespace boost_1_69_0 {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
inline void save_construct_data(Archive& ar, const amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer* comLayer, const unsigned int version) {
    ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp(
        BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(amp::communication::ICommunicationLayer), 
        boost::serialization::base_object<amp::communication::ICommunicationLayer>(*comLayer)
    );

    ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("path", const_cast<std::string>(comLayer->getPath());

    // other options
}

template<class Archive>
inline void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer* comLayer, const unsigned int version) {
    ar >> boost::serialization::base_object<amp::communication::ICommunicationLayer>(*comLayer);

    std::string path;
    ar >> path;

    // other options

    new(comLayer) amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer(path, baudrate, /* other options */);
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct data is an *addition* to regular serialization. You still need to serialize. As a matter of fact, serializing `base_object` needs to be in the constructed-object `serialize` implementation.

Also keep in mind that you need to EXPORT *after* including the relevant archive type(s).

You have a number of spots with redundant top-level const (even a const-cast). Top-level const on return type/arguments isn't part of the function signature.

Finally, I don't know what `namespace boost_1_69_0` is, but that should not work. Use `namespace boost`. If you're playing with macros to define it like that, I'd suggest to stop doing that. Instead consider putting the overloads in the ADL-associated namespace for your types!

Here's the whole thing made self-contained and working:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/210c491504a14a1d)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <chrono>

// BASE
namespace amp::communication {
    using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;

    class ICommunicationLayer {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Archive> inline void serialize(Archive&, unsigned){}

      public:
        virtual ~ICommunicationLayer();
        virtual size_t write(char const* const buffer, size_t buffSize)                   = 0;
        virtual size_t readUntil(std::vector<char>& buffer, char delim, duration timeout) = 0;
    };
} // namespace amp::communication

// DERIVED
//#include "ICommunicationLayer.h"

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>

namespace amp { namespace communication {

    class RS485CommunicationLayer final : public ICommunicationLayer {
      public:
        RS485CommunicationLayer(std::string const& path, unsigned baud_rate)
            : path(path)
            , baud_rate(baud_rate) {}

        ~RS485CommunicationLayer();

        size_t      write(char const* const buffer, const size_t size) override;
        size_t      readUntil(std::vector<char>& buffer, char delim, duration timeout) override;
        std::string getPath() const { return path; }
        unsigned    getBaudrate() const { return baud_rate; }

      private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
            ar& boost::make_nvp("ICommunicationLayer",
                                boost::serialization::base_object<ICommunicationLayer>(*this));
        }

        std::string path;
        unsigned    baud_rate;
        // rest of impl
    };

    // ADL resolved overloads
    template <class Archive>
    inline void save_construct_data(Archive& ar, RS485CommunicationLayer const* p, unsigned) {
        auto path = p->getPath();
        unsigned baud_rate = p->getBaudrate();
        ar& BOOST_NVP(path) & BOOST_NVP(baud_rate);
    }

    template <class Archive>
    inline void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, RS485CommunicationLayer* p, unsigned) {
        std::string path;
        unsigned baud_rate;
        ar >> BOOST_NVP(path) >> BOOST_NVP(baud_rate);
        new (p) RS485CommunicationLayer(path, baud_rate);
    }
}} // namespace amp::communication

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(amp::communication::ICommunicationLayer)

#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(amp::communication::ICommunicationLayer)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer)

int main() {
    using namespace amp::communication;
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<ICommunicationLayer>;

    std::vector<Ptr> ptrs{nullptr, std::make_shared<RS485CommunicationLayer>("hello", 115'200)}, roundtrip;
    ptrs.push_back(ptrs.back()); // one duplicate for testing purposes

    std::stringstream xml;
    {
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(xml);
        oa << boost::make_nvp("root", ptrs);
    }

    std::cout << xml.str();
    {
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(xml);
        ia >> boost::make_nvp("root", roundtrip);
    }

    bool verify = roundtrip.size() == ptrs.size();
    verify &= (roundtrip.at(0) == nullptr);
    verify &= (roundtrip.at(1) == roundtrip.at(2));

    std::cout << "Roundtrip verify " << (verify?"OK":"FAILED") << std::endl;
}

// to satisfy linker
namespace amp { namespace communication {
    ICommunicationLayer::~ICommunicationLayer()         = default;
    RS485CommunicationLayer::~RS485CommunicationLayer() = default;
    size_t RS485CommunicationLayer::write(char const*, size_t) { return 0; }
    size_t RS485CommunicationLayer::readUntil(std::vector<char>&, char, duration) { return 0; }
}} // namespace amp::communication
```

Prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="19">
<root class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <count>3</count>
    <item_version>1</item_version>
    <item class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="1">
        <px class_id="-1"></px>
    </item>
    <item>
        <px class_id="2" class_name="amp::communication::RS485CommunicationLayer" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_0">
            <path>hello</path>
            <baud_rate>115200</baud_rate>
            <ICommunicationLayer class_id="3" tracking_level="0" version="0"></ICommunicationLayer>
        </px>
    </item>
    <item>
        <px class_id_reference="2" object_id_reference="_0"></px>
    </item>
</root>
</boost_serialization>

Roundtrip verify OK
```

### Afterthought

Perhaps the best location for load/save construct data is as hidden friends. That way you don't even need public accessors for every bit of construct-data:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/294d1cc4b84d04dd)**

```
class RS485CommunicationLayer final : public ICommunicationLayer {
  public:
    RS485CommunicationLayer(std::string const& path, unsigned baud_rate)
        : path(path)
        , baud_rate(baud_rate) {}

    ~RS485CommunicationLayer() override;

    size_t write(char const* const buffer, const size_t size) override;
    size_t readUntil(std::vector<char>& buffer, char delim, duration timeout) override;

  private:
    std::string path;
    unsigned    baud_rate;
    // rest of impl

    template <class Archive>
    friend void save_construct_data(Archive& ar, RS485CommunicationLayer const* p, unsigned) {
        auto     path      = p->path;
        unsigned baud_rate = p->baud_rate;
        ar&      BOOST_NVP(path) & BOOST_NVP(baud_rate);
    }

    template <class Archive>
    friend void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, RS485CommunicationLayer* p, unsigned) {
        std::string path;
        unsigned    baud_rate;
        ar >> BOOST_NVP(path) >> BOOST_NVP(baud_rate);
        new (p) RS485CommunicationLayer(path, baud_rate);
    }

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar& boost::make_nvp("ICommunicationLayer",
                            boost::serialization::base_object<ICommunicationLayer>(*this));
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for taking all this time! This is great! I have a question about the `friend void load_construct_data` though. I've never seen friend functions, but when I read boost's docs I see that that function needs to be specified in their namespace. Wouldn't that be a problem? Also, I'm not allowed to put any (template) function definitions in the header files and I tried doing the declaration in .h and the definition in .cpp. But they don't seem to link up and I got an (almost) empty xml

Comment: Oh, btw the reason for boost_1_69_0 is because otherwise I get: `error: namespace alias ‘boost’ not allowed here, assuming ‘boost_1_69_0’`. I didn't change any macro's but my company might've.

Comment: Okay. Assuming they know what they're doing then. Probably to allow side-by-side packaging of versions. It's fine as long as all your code (including any shared boost libraries) compiles with the same assumptions. It's not something I've encountered before

Comment: (Mmm. If this were my responsibility, I'd say you need to be including headers/build config that already contains `#define boost boost_1_69_0`. Obviously, it is not, just worth checking that you didn't miss some config/include)

Comment: I missed the first comment: the friend *is* in the surrounding namespace, except it can **only** be found via ADL, which is exactly what you want. See [GotW "What's in a class - The Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm) and also related [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](https://embeddedartistry.com/fieldatlas/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation/).

Comment: Re.: "I'm not allowed to put any (template) function definitions in the header files" there must be some confusion. Template functions can practically [*only* be defined in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). The only exception is when you extern-declare explicit instantiations, which you might do if you use only a limited set of archive types.

Comment: Apropos of nothing: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478668/boost-serialization-using-polymorphic-archives

Comment: Hey thanks for all the comments! These really help! Regarding the boost namespace part: I am including boost/access.hpp which almost starts with the line `namespace boost_1_69_0 {} namespace boost = boost_1_69_0;` But it doesn't seem to stick well with the compiler.

Comment: Regarding the header/source seperation. I've been trying to change the mind of my supervisor but he won't budge. I'm an intern, so I don't have a lot of say on the matter. I needed to work around this situation for the last 3 months. But if you say that this is the only way, I might try again.

Comment: Regarding the friend function. With surrounding namespace you mean that it's in `::amp` or `::` (root). Doesn't that mean the line should be `friend void boost::serialization::load_construct_data(Archive& ar, RS485CommunicationLayer* p, unsigned)`? (with boost::serialization:: added in front of the function). Just checking.

Comment: I didn't say it's the only way, it's just that templates come with these constraints (so, look at explicit instantiations)

Comment: I cannot find any trace of `boost_1_69_0` in *any version* of *any boost library* (outside release notes/CI scripts). This is not a boost thing (note `boost/access.hpp` doesn't exist either, but you probably meant `boost/serialization/access.hpp`)